# How to connect Spring with MySQL database?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I have a simple project, based on [this guide](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/). I created a simple REST interface and I want it to use my database. I added Hibernate to the dependencies and created the DAO class. I'm using Spring Tool-Suite for IDE. As far as I understand I should add some beans to tell the classes what to use but I don't understand how. Here are my classes.

**Application.java**

```
package com.learnspring.projectfirst;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

     public static void main(String[] args) {
            SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
        }
}
```

**Marker.java**

```
package com.learnspring.projectfirst;

@Entity
public class Marker {

    @Id
    @Column
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;
    @Column
    private double longitude;
    @Column
    private double latitude;

    @Column
    private String address;

    public Marker() {
        // Empty constructor
    }

    public Marker(long id, double longitude, double latitude, String address) {
        this.id = id;
        this.longitude = longitude;
        this.latitude = latitude;
        this.address = address;
    }

    //Getters and Setters
}
```

**MarkerController.java**

```
package com.learnspring.projectfirst.controller;

@Controller
public class MarkerController {
    private Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(MarkerController.class.getName());
    @Autowired
    private MarkerServiceImplementation markerService;

    @RequestMapping(value="/markers", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody List<Marker> getMarkers(@RequestParam(value="city", defaultValue="") String city) {
        return this.markerService.getAllMarkers();
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/markers/new", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody Marker addMarker(@RequestBody Marker marker) {
        this.markerService.addMarker(marker);
        return marker;
    }

}
```

**MarkerDaoImplementation.java**

```
package com.learnspring.projectfirst.dao;

@Repository
public class MarkerDaoImplementation implements MarkerDaoInterface {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Override
    public void addMarker(Marker marker) {
        this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(marker);
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteMarker(int markerId) {
        this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().delete(this.getMarker(markerId));
    }

    @Override
    public Marker getMarker(int markerId) {
        return (Marker) this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().get(Marker.class, markerId);
    }

    @Override
    public List<Marker> getAllMarkers() {
        return this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from Marker").list();
    }

}
```

**MarkerServiceImplementation.java**

```
package com.learnspring.projectfirst.service;

@Service
public class MarkerServiceImplementation implements MarkerServiceInterface {
    @Autowired
    private MarkerDaoImplementation markerDao;

    @Transactional
    public void addMarker(Marker marker) {
        this.markerDao.addMarker(marker);
    }

    @Transactional
    public void deleteMarker(int markerId) {
        this.markerDao.deleteMarker(markerId);
    }

    @Transactional
    public Marker getMarker(int markerId) {
        return this.markerDao.getMarker(markerId);
    }

    @Transactional
    public List<Marker> getAllMarkers() {
        return this.markerDao.getAllMarkers();
    }
}
```

And here is the file structure:

[image]

I understand that I should tell my program the database name and the columns using beans but I don't understand how. How can I link the java code to the beans? Sorry I pasted so much code, I just wanted to make sure you have everything needed. Thank you in advance!

Comment: There are 10s of samples on github. see this search https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Agithub.com+spring+4+mysql

Comment: Take a look at Spring Boot [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-sql.html).

Answer (score 1):

This is the one you need: [Spring Boot with MySQL](http://blog.netgloo.com/2014/08/17/use-mysql-database-in-a-spring-boot-web-application-through-hibernate/)

Answer (score 0):

Refer this example : [Spring MVC with JdbcTemplate Example](http://www.codejava.net/frameworks/spring/spring-mvc-with-jdbctemplate-example)

Comment: In this example the beans are added through java. Am I understanding right?

Answer (score 0):

The annotations in your "Marker" class determine the MySQL table and column names (based on the class and class variable names). The tablename will be "marker", with the columns "id", "longitude", "latitude", "address".

You forgot the most important part in your code: your spring configuration. it determines how the SessionFactory instance will be initialized before being injected into your DAO class. Here you have to set an appropriate connection to the MySQL Server (e.g. via an JNDI Resource)

Comment: Yeah, I know about the annotations in the Marker class. Where should I add the spring configuration and should I do something specific to tell my program to use it?

Comment: There are several alternatives for that (XML or java configuration). I don't know about the spring boot configuration, but i guess you can use an annotation (@Configuration) for that